# Xamarin Android Essentials Location Permission

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, permissions, android-permissions

I am trying to create a Xamarin cross-platform app, and Android version requires location access. If the user selects **"Do Not Ask Again"** checkbox to deny Location Permission, Android does not prompt for location access again. The user has to manually provide access from the phone settings.

Is there a way to check if the user has selected **"Do Not Ask Again"** from pages other than **MainActivity.cs**? When the user logs in again, I would like to display an alert to the user if he has selected **"Do Not Ask Again"**.

I found that **ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()** is the only way to find out if the user has selected **"Do Not Ask Again"**. But itseems like this method can only be invoked from **MainActivity.cs**.

Comment: I read through the links which you shared in the below post, but I am still not clear about implementing (ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage)) in another activity. Could you please post an example?

Comment: You just need  call `ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` method in the activity,forexample,there are two activities,one is MainActivity,i need check the permission in the second activity(ActivityB),i just need to call the method in ActivityB directly

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I used **ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale** method in Mainactivity.cs, and called it from another activity. But I get an error message - **"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Activity.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(string)'".** Am I still missing something?

Comment: Try to use `ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission)` or `ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,permission)`

Comment: I am trying to call  `ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission)` defined in MainActivity.cs from **another .cs file**, other than MainActivity.cs with `if (ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation))
                {
                    
                }` . But it throws an error - "The name **'ActivityCompat'** does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Do you reference the `Android.Support.V4.App` ,add `using Android.Support.V4.App;`

Comment: I am using the reference in MainActivity.cs, but not in the other .cs file, since I am trying to run the app on iOS as well. Also, the other .cs files does not allow me to add `Android.Support.V4.App`

Comment: Try to use `ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission)`both MainActivity and anotheractivity.Or you could show your activity codes.

Comment: I get the error - **"The name 'ActivityCompat' does not exist in the current context"** when I call **ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale** from another activity

**MainActivity.cs**:

`
            if (ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation))
            {
                //  
            }
`
**Test.cs**:
`
                        if (ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permissions))
                        {
                            // display to user
                        }
`

Comment: Have you installed `Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat ` nuget ?

Comment: Yeah. I have installed this package.

Comment: That's weird. Maybe you could try creating a new blank project

Comment: Could it work now ?

Answer (score 0):

> But itseems like this method can only be invoked from MainActivity.cs.

You could call the method in every activity,included in fragment.

For example

in **Activity** :

```
 // Here, thisActivity is the current activity

if (ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage))
    {
       // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
       // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
       // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.   
    }
```

you could look at [Explain why the app needs permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

in **Fragment** (support v4):

```
if (ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage))
    {

    }
```

you could look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#shouldshowrequestpermissionrationale)

and there are changes in other packages,like in (support v13)

```
boolean shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale (Fragment fragment, 
            String permission)
```

you could look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentCompat#shouldshowrequestpermissionrationale)